# How I set the inputFilter to not allow white space in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

How I set the inputFilter to not allow white space in zend framework 2?

I'm trying this:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'codigo',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'not_empty',
                ),
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                 array(
                     'name' => 'Alnum',
                     'allowwhitespace' => false,
                 ),
            ),
        )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points in your code needs minor tweaks;

- [ValidatorPluginManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/ValidatorPluginManager.php#L23-107) uses normalized aliases to invoke
  validators by cannonical names, which means 'not_empty' is not a
  valid alias, it should be 'notempty' or 'NotEmpty'.
- Also your [Alnum](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/I18n/Filter/Alnum.php) filter signature seems invalid. You should
  provide additional options inside the `options` sub key with underscores. (Yes, this is really weird inconsistency)

Try this:

```
$filter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
$filter->add(array(
            'name'       => 'codigo',
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                ),
            ),
            'filters' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'              => 'Alnum',
                     'options'           => array(
                        'allow_white_space' => false,
                    )
                 ),
            ),
        ));

$filter->setData(['codigo' => 'Whitespace exists']);
if($filter->isValid() === false) {
    // You'll fall here with a value like multiple spaces etc..
    var_dump($filter->getMessages());
} else {
    var_dump($filter->getValues()); // Prints ['codigo' => string 'Whitespaceexists']
}
```